# JIRA (Greenhopper) How to add Story behindhand (if it's already completed)?

Tags: jira, greenhopper

Could you please tip me - how to add the Story(is) behindhand? I work on the project some time already and we decided to start using JIRA. So at the moment I hve some tasks (stories) completed already. And I want to add them in the past to JIRA (Greenhopper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found how to do that [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/81654/how-do-i-create-a-sprint-in-the-past). Quoting just in case it will be deleted on original page for some reasons:

*Question:*

> I've imported my user stories from another system, but I cannot seem to add them to a sprint dated in the past. I get the error: "You must specify a start date that is not in the past.". How can I work around this to import past sprints?

*Answer:*

> **Create a sprint NOT in the past.** Drag your tasks into said sprint. **Update said sprint to be a past date.** Close said sprint.